# Align button for right in the middle of TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml, android-button

I want to align button for right in the middle of TextView like WhatsApp. Android studio's layout preview screen is showing right but at phone it is not align middle of TextView, align bottom of screen.

**No problem with fragment alone but when fragment inside activity, problem occurs. I understand that my activity layout is wrong.**

How can I align send button?

**Whatsapp button:**
[image]

**My button at Android Studio preview:**
[image]

**My button at phone:**
[image]

my fragment layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userNames"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Hello Nilu Pilu"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreen" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_log_out" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:tabMode="scrollable">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_action"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                app:defaultQueryHint="@string/searchForName"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:queryHint="@string/searchForName"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_24" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/share_list_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Couldn't understand the issue, I can say what WhatsApp does is that is a FAB button you can set padding of TextView as per FAB buttons size and you can place arrow image to the left of the TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO need to use nested `RelativeLayout` you can achieve it only using single `RelativeLayout`

> Try this using `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userNames"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Hello Nilu Pilu"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreen" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_log_out" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Try this using `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userNames"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Hello Nilu Pilu"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_log_out"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: No problem with fragment alone but when fragment inside activity, problem occurs. I understand that my activity layout is wrong. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use `ConstraintLayout` layout instead of `RelativeLayout` and here is your code with `ConstraintLayout`,  which will work perfectly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/emptyListColor"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userNames"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottomView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/send_circle"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/attach_send2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: No problem with fragment alone but when fragment inside activity, problem occurs. I understand that my activity layout is wrong. Please help me

Comment: Is this your activity layout?

Comment: Yeap I added activity layout

Comment: I changed Linearlayout to RelativeLayout from Activity and fixed. Very thanks